# Socket.io event listener not working on server side

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket IO rooms in my project.

On the server side:

```
const PORT = 4200

const server = require('http').createServer(require('express')())
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

server.listen(PORT)

const room = 'example' 

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.join(room); 
});
```

From emit data from a server to client, I am using `io.sockets.in(room).emit(path, data)` and it works perfectly.

The problem is when I listen for events from the client side that code is not fired.

```
io.sockets.on(path, () => console.log('FIRED'))
```

The path is definitely correct.

What is wrong? Am I using the `on` event incorrect?

Comment: Hey. It seems a lot of the code is missing.
Can you provide a minimal, complete example of the code that is not working?